# While Loop Statement

Tags: java, while-loop

I am having trouble understanding some code in Java. I have researched around but I am still having trouble fully understanding it.

```
boolean showShip = false; //set the ship to be hidden by default

while(!showShip) //dont get this while loop
{
  val = promptForInt("\n" + "Guess again. "); 

  if(val == randomShipLocation)
  {
    System.out.println("\n" +" BOOM!");
    showShip = false;
    riverLength[val] = 1; // mark a hit
  }
  else {
    riverLength[val] = -1; // mark a miss
  }

  displayRiver(riverLength, showShip);
}
```

The part I am getting stuck on is the `while(!showShip)` part. What does this statement mean?

Comment: Can you be more precise about which part of that code is unclear for you? Do you know how `while` loops work? Do you know what `!` operator does?

Comment: Yes I understand it in this context  `(A != B) is true`. But I don't understand it in the context of the question

Comment: I wonder what "researched" means in your case. A Google search is not a good way to research issues that involve punctuation such as `!`, as Google ignores most punctuation. When you say "research" this should include going through the documentation, though.

Comment: @RealSkeptic Was it really necessary to downvote this question? I searched Stack Overflow along with various other websites and I couldn't find anything that explained the use of ! in a while loop as shown in the question. I understand the use in `(A != B) is true` just not with a boolean value.

Comment: It is a short notation for the same `while (showShip != true)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> while(!showShip) // don't get this while loop
> ```

Using `!` inverts the `boolean`, so the loop condition is a short way of saying

```
while(showShip == false) // This is the long way
```

Of course in order to exit the loop you need to set `showShip` to `true`, but the body of your loop never does it. Therefore, the loop is *infinite*. Most likely, the intention has been to do

```
System.out.println("\n" +" BOOM!");
showShip = true;
```

**Note:** A short way to write "continue while a variable is `true` is

```
while (showShip) // skip the == true part
```

Comment: Thank you great answer much appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

`showShip` is a boolean variable, which means that it can be either `true` or `false`. `while(!showShip)` means that the while loop should keep looping (repeating) as long as the value of `showShip` is `false`.